# How can I test my app development directly on an Android phone?

Tags: android, size, screen, apk

I can't find an emulator that fits my mobile screen size, so I created a custom emulator, but unfortunately, even though it's actually according to the size of my mobile, the graphics are showing differently on the actual device.

1. How to detect a 2.3 device which is not listed within the avd
   manager?
2. If that's not possible, what should I do to test the development
   directly on the mobile without having to export a .pak file every
   time?

Comment: Please define "showing differently."

Comment: If i placed lets say a button 20  dp from the left, the emulator shows it differently than the actual mobile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the phone, go to Settings -> Applications. Enable "Unknown sources".

Then select "Development" and enable "USB debugging" and "Stay Awake".

Connect the phone to your PC via USB and it should appear in the list of available devices to use for debugging.

Comment: It came up on the available devices, and i stoped viewing the phone on ubuntu, but it came up as ??????? and unknown.

Comment: Hmmm, mine did that a few times sometime back (maybe a year ago). I can't remember what the problem was, sorry - it might have just been a case of restarting the AVD manager, not sure. I run Win XP so can't say whether it could be an Ubuntu issue or not.

Comment: Just to update i worked it out, turns out i have to setup the usb adb for linux ubuntu http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html. after that it also failed because of lacked permissions, so i googled the error, and turns out i have to kill ado server and restart it as root then the device poped open. Thanks for the lead MisterSquonk

Comment: @zf.: Ah, good to hear - I'll make note of the steps in case I come across any other Ubuntu users with similar problems. Thanks for the update. Good luck.